# Vue - Setting data before blur listener fires

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a custom dropdown that will eventually use a dynamically filtered list. Right now I am trying to have the a click action fire before the dropdown disappears.

My expected action is:

- When clicking within the `<input>` the dropdown list will show (`@focus`)
- When not within the `<input>`, the dropdown list will not display (`@blur`)
- When the user clicks one of the `<a> {{ Item }} </a>` in the list, it will set the `liveSearch` value to the clicked item.

Right now, the first two desired actions are working, but it seems that the blur is hiding the clicked item before setting the data. I've tried making the `isDropdownOpen` data be a function that toggles true/false bit this stops the hide/show working.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    isDropdownOpen: false,
    liveSearch: '',
    queryKeyFilter: ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'] // Replace with your own data source
  },
  methods: {
    setQuery(item) {
      this.liveSearch = item;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.scrollable-menu {
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="app">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input @focus="isDropdownOpen = true" @blur="isDropdownOpen = false" type="text" class="form-control"
      placeholder="Search..." v-model="liveSearch" />
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" :class="{ show: isDropdownOpen }">
    <div class="scrollable-menu">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" v-for="item in queryKeyFilter" @click="setQuery(item)">
        {{ item }}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think you're going to need to use a different event than "blur" to dismiss the dropdown, because that's always going to fire before the click event elsewhere does. The usual approach is mouseout on the full dropdown element, with a short delay cancellable by a mouse enter, plus watch for click/touch events outside the element.

Comment: (I mean you could go with hacky jank like having the blur event set a timeout before closing the dropdown, but that sort of thing always leads to confusing race conditions later on)

Comment: Thanks for that. So the click event can remain? And then keep a listener to any click outside the div? Last thing would be adding a hide event in the setQuery() function?